# populate dataframe with loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new into python but and already spent a lot of time without any visible progress on this issue.
hope someone could direct me on my question!
i have some track data with samples collected.

| track | direction | samples |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | forward | 11 |
| 1 | backward | 10 |
| 2 | forward | 40 |
| 2 | backward | 30 |

and i need to **populate dataframe** with **multiplied** number of rows for each **direction** for each **track** by number in the column **"samples"**

the **output** should be something like that:

| track | direction | sample |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | forward | 1 |
| 1 | forward | 2 |
| 1 | forward | 3 |
| 1 | forward | ... |
| 1 | forward | 11 |
| 1 | backward | 1 |
| 1 | backward | ... |
| 1 | backward | 10 |
| 2 | forward | 1 |
| 2 | forward | ... |
| 2 | forward | 40 |
| 2 | backward | 1 |
| 2 | backward | ... |
| 2 | backward | 30 |

thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could give an example output/code.

Comment: Hi Mohhamad! tthe output should be the table in the end of the post (second). i'm a bit in a trouble fixing it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Apply` `range` over your sample and `explode` the list and `join` to other columns.

```
df = df[['track', 'direction']].join(
        df['samples'].apply(range)
                     .explode()
                     .add(1)
                     .rename('sample')
     )
```

```
>>> df
    track direction sample
0       1   forward      1
0       1   forward      2
0       1   forward      3
0       1   forward      4
0       1   forward      5
..    ...       ...    ...
3       2  backward     26
3       2  backward     27
3       2  backward     28
3       2  backward     29
3       2  backward     30

[91 rows x 3 columns]
```

The solution of @ThePyGuy is valid too:

```
df.assign(sample=df['samples'].add(1)
                              .apply(lambda x: range(1,x))) \
  .explode('sample') \
  .drop(columns=['samples'])
```

**Performance**

```
%timeit df[['track', 'direction']].join(df['samples'].apply(range).explode().add(1).rename('sample'))
2.75 ms ± 356 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df.assign(sample=df['samples'].add(1).apply(lambda x: range(1,x))).explode('sample').drop(columns=['samples'])
5.65 ms ± 308 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

*It's not significant for this sample, however both operations are  slow.*

Comment: I think you could avoid using `join`, something like: `df.assign(sample=df['samples'].add(1).apply(lambda x: range(1,x))).explode('sample').drop(columns=['samples'])`

Comment: wow! @Corralien you a magician! this works exactly how it should!)
thank you!
have one more question -- i have for each of these samples a timestamp in excel but filled in columns.
so for each track-direction pair i have same amount of cells representing time when the samples were collected. could you please suggest an option here?

Comment: @ThePyGuy. I updated my answer with your solution. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
(df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['samples'])]
 .assign(samples = lambda x: x.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1))
```